# Jmeter CLI: How to get separate JTL reports for separate thread groups in Test plan (reference provided)?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, report

I am running Jmeter from CLI. In the end of test run I get one Jmeter report, which I need to further reconcile to separate results of different thread groups.

I want to two different JTLs for two different thread groups inside Test Plan.

I have gone through this solution but since content on this page is very limited. I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Reference: https://qnalist.com/questions/700654/multiple-thread-groups-jtl-file

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) or [Simple Data Writer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) listener to each of the thread group.
2. In `Filename` field, give full path to the file, in which you want to save the results. (different file/path for different Aggregate Report listener in each thread group, otherwise, results will be overridden)
3. Optionally, you can configure the values to be saved in the file, using `Configure` button.

**Note:** If you are using, then no need to add `-l result.jtl` file. JMeter saves the results in the given path/file. This is optional, If you specify, it will collects all the results (which is your current scenario).

Added screenshot for the reference:
[image]

Comment: where is `simple data writer` in attached image?

Comment: image is for `Aggregate Report`. both are similar. you can use any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) in order to filter out results belonging to this or that Thread Group (just make sure they have different names).

Example usage:

> jmeter\lib\ext\FilterResults.bat --output-file threadgroup1.csv --input-file results.jtl --include-label-regex true --include-labels "P[1-3].*"

The tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)